Two ways to define a quotient topology. Are they equivalent?
Consider a topological group $G$ whose topology comprises open sets $U_a$.
For a subgroup $K<G$ with an induced topology assembled of the sets $K\cap U_a$, the canonical map
$$
\pi:\, G\longrightarrow G/K 
$$
assigns to each element $g\in G$ the coset $gK$ it is in.
Now, two methods to equip the left quotient space $G/K$ with a topology.
DEFINITION 1.
A subset $V\subset G/K$ is open iff its preimage $\pi^{-1} V$ is open in $G$.
This must be the finest topology for which $\pi$ is continuous.
DEFINITION 2.
$V\equiv\pi(U) = \{u K : u\in U\}$ is open in $G/K$ iff $U$ is open in $G$.
QUESTION:
Are DEF 1 and DEF 2 equivalent?
AMENDMENT: 
After a kind consultation by the user `Jakobian' below, I see that DEF 2 $\Longrightarrow$ DEF 1, because the openness of $U$ warrants the openness of $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)=\bigcup_{k\in K} U k$ as a union of open sets.
The proof, it seems, works in one direction only.
Indeed, if the openness of $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)$ does not warrant that of $U$, I am unable to state that DEF 1 implies DEF 2.

The quotient map $\pi:G\to G/H$ is open from what I recall. So yeah, they should be equivalent.

@Jakobian Open - or continuous??

Both open and continuous. If $U\subseteq G$ is open then $\pi^{-1}\pi(U) = U\cdot K = \bigcup_{g\in K} Ug$ open as union of open sets. This implies $\pi(U)$ is open.

@Jakobian And if a map is both open and continuous, then it establishes an unambiguous correspondence between sets in the two spaces, correct?

In the second case you define $V \subset G/K$ is open if it is of the form $V = UK$ for some open $U \subseteq G$?

If $U\subseteq G$ is open, then what you wrote as $U\cdot K$, which in reality should be either $\pi(U)$ or ${u\cdot K : u\in U}$ since $U\cdot K$ is not a subset of of $G/K$, will open in quotient topology. And if $V\subseteq G/H$ is open in quotient topology, then $V = \pi(\pi^{-1}(V)) = {u\cdot K : u\in \pi^{-1}(V)}$ is of the desired form.

@Jakobian Yes, I agree. Writing the subset of $G/K$ as $UK$ would be too informal. An accurate notation must be, as you said, ${u\cdot K : u\in U}$.  Would you consider summarising your comments into an answer? This would give me a pleasant opportunity to give you a full credit of points. Thank you for your time and help!

@Jakobian You have demonstrated that if $U$ is open in $G$ then  $\pi^{-1}\pi(U) = U\cdot K = \bigcup_{k\in K} Uk$ is open also, as a union of open sets. Could you please help me prove the inverse: if $\pi^{-1}\pi(U) = U\cdot K = \bigcup_{k\in K} Uk$ is open, then so is $U$.

@psl2Z Yes, exactly so

@Michael_1812 If $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)$ is open, then $U$ doesn't have to be open.

@Jakobian If the openness of $\pi^{-1}\pi(U)$ does not necessitate the openness of $U$, then the two Definitions in my post are not necessarily equivalent.  Let $V\equiv\pi(U) = {uK: u\in U  }$ and $\pi^{-1}(V)=\pi^{-1}\pi(U) = \bigcup_{k\in K} Uk$. Then the decreeing that $V$ is open in $G/K$ iff $U$ is open in G is not equivalent to the decreeing that $V$ is open in $G/K$ iff $\pi^{-1}(V)=\pi^{-1}\pi(U)$ is open in $G$.

@Jakobian I have formulated this question as an Amendment in the end of my post. And, once again, many thanks for your kind patience!

Definition 2 is not well-defined because there can be $U_1 \neq U_2$ such that $\pi(U_1) = \pi(U_2)$ but e.g. $U_1$ open and $U_2$ not. You can choose if you well-define it by demanding $V$ is open if for all $U$ with $V=\pi(U)$, $U$ is open, or by demanding there exists at least one open $U$ with $V=\pi(U)$. One of these should be the correct version and equivalent to definition 1, the other one should be nonsense.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you indeed for this comment. Can you tell me from the top of your head which of the three options warrants the equivalence of the Defs?

@Michael_1812 I thought it's more fun if you figure it out for yourself. By the way, I thought I presented two options, not three.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Sorry, my misprint. Two it were. As for the choice between the two, I am not even sure if it is always possible to have all such $U$ open, for which $V=\pi(U)$. So I would demand that there is at least one such $U$. Now, could you kindly show me how DEF 1 implies DEF 2, with this correction taken into account?

Your previous definition of definition 2 was better - we demand that $\pi(U)$ are open for open $U$. You can't guarantee equivalence. For example, if $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to {0}$ is a quotient map then any non-empty set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\pi^{-1}\pi(A) = \mathbb{R}$ is open...

@Jakobian How would you recommend to shape Def 2 ? At present, it is: $\pi(U)$ is open iff $U$ is open. Should I change "iff" to "if". I would much appreciate a formulation you find acceptable.

@Michael_1812 Yes, or $V\subseteq G/K$ is open when there exists open $U\subseteq G$ such that $V = \pi(U)$.

As it is currently written, "definition 2":

$V\equiv\pi(U) = \{u K : u\in U\}$ is open in $G/K$ iff $U$ is open in $G$.

is actually not well-defined, because for a given $V \subseteq G/K$ there is rarely a unique $U \subseteq G$ such that $V = \pi(U)$.
Example: Let $G = (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R, +)$ with its standard topology, $K = \{ (0,y): y \in \mathbb R\}$, $$V = \{ g + K : g =(x,y) \text{ with } -1<x<1\},$$
and note that e.g. for $$U_1 := \{(x,0) : -1<x<1\} \qquad \text{ and } \qquad U_2 := \{(x,y) : -1<x<1, y \in \mathbb R\}$$ we have $\pi(U_1)=\pi(U_2)=V$, but $U_2$ is open in $G$ while $U_1$ is not.

So as it stands, definition 2 is not actually a definition hence cannot be equivalent to definition 1.
As I said in a comment, you need some quantifiers to make that attempt an actual definition. A first attempt might be:

Attempt 1: Call $V \subset G/K$ open iff all $U \subseteq G$ with $V=\pi(U)$ are open subsets of $G$.

But think if that would work. The previous example would show that with this definition, the $V$ in there would not be open; but should it be via definition 1? (In fact, I think one could very rarely show that even the full space G/K were open in this attempt; i.e. in general, this attempt would not even define a topology.)
Much better suited might be what several commenters have implicitly or explicitly suggested:

Attempt 2: Call $V \subset G/K$ open iff there is at least one open $U \subseteq G$ with $V=\pi(U)$.

Note that the answer by user Chris actually shows, assuming definition 1, that if $U$ is open in $G$, then $\pi(U)$ is open in $G/K$. So this gives that every set $V \subset G/K$ that is "open" as per attempt 2 is also "open" as per definition 1. Now start with an open set $V$ as per definition 1 and find at least one open $U \subseteq G$ with $\pi(U) = V$. Hint: Look through definition 1 for sets that are open in $G$ and map to $V$.

Dear Torsten, thank you for this answer. You probably made a slip of the pen by saying that if $U$ is open in $G$ then $\pi(U)$ is open in $G$. You probably wanted to say that $\pi(U)$ is open in $G/K$.

Torsten, regarding your last two sentences. Is my understanding correct that you suggest to employ the preimage $\pi^{-1}(V)$ as the one $U$ needed to be open in DEF 2 ?

@Michael_1812 You're correct on both. I've edited the mistake, thanks.

Torsten, many thanks for your time and consultation!
